# Java Selenium WebDriver code to implement Verify instead of Assert

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, assertions, verify

I am not able to understand how to write Java code to implement `Verify`. I am always seeing the code to implement `Assert` but not for `Verify`. I know for `Assert`, we need to write the code as below:

```
Assert.assertTrue()
```

or

```
Assert.assertEquals() etc.
```

But what about `Verify`? I want to verify the title of my application once the user is logged into the application by using `verify`. How can I do this?

Comment: What Test framework have you used? Is it TestNG or JUnit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the TestNG framework which only supports Assert statements. It doesn't support Verify statements. You can visit the following URL for TestNG Javadoc:

http://testng.org/javadocs/

From http://seleniumonlinetrainingexpert.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/what-is-the-difference-between-assert-and-verify-in-selenium/

When Assertion fails all test steps after that line of code are skipped
When a “verify” fails, the test will continue executing and logging the failure.

If you want to use Verify statements then you will have to use the Junit framework.

Comment: Yes that is correct I verified just now. Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: What package does it need to import for using 'verify' with JUnit?

Answer (score 1):

TestNG does not support verify statements, but they can be implemented easily. The simplest way is to use Java StringBuffer in your test method like below,

```
@Test
public void verifyTest(){  

    /* buffer to hold your errors */
    StringBuffer errorBuffer = new StringBuffer();      

    /* verification 1 */
    try{        
        Assert.assertEquals("value1", "value!");            
    }catch(AssertionError e){           
        errorBuffer.append(e.getMessage() + "\n");      
    }       

    /* verification 2 */
    try{            
        Assert.assertEquals("value2", "value!");            
    }catch(AssertionError e){           
        errorBuffer.append(e.getMessage());     
    }

    if(errorBuffer.length() > 0){
        throw new AssertionError(errorBuffer.toString()); 
    }

}
```

For more advanced implementation you can use TestNG's IInvokedMethodListener interface where you need to implement two methods from that interface,

```
public class TestMethodListener implements IInvokedMethodListener{

    @Override
    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {

        if(method.isTestMethod()){              
            /* create new error buffer object */                
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {

        if(method.isTestMethod()){              
            /* process your test result for verification errors stored in error buffer
             * and modify your testResult object accordingly
             */                 
        }

    }

}
```

Most of the time we don't have to go for advanced implementation. Simple StringBuffer should work. But if you want to use verify statements frequently in your test then implementing IInvokedMethodListener would be reasonable. If you are interested in advanced implementation then please check this blog https://muthutechno.wordpress.com/2015/01/26/implementing-verify-statements-for-testng-framework/

Answer (score 0):

Even if TestNG does not support verification directly you can create soft assertions which will act like verifications. Kindly check this link: http://seleniumexamples.com/blog/guide/using-soft-assertions-in-testng/